# Calculating number of unit cells in aluminium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, textbook-erratum

So there's this problem which asked me to calculate the number of unit cells in 1 cm³ of Aluminum given that it forms a ccp(cubic close packed) structure. I calculated this by finding out the mass of 1 cm³ of Aluminum (which is 2.7 gram) and the mass of 1 unit cell of aluminum (Mass of 1 mole of aluminum * 4 / Total number of atoms). 4 because there are four atoms in a ccp structure. And then dividing the mass of 1 cm³ by mass of unit cell which should give me the answer.

I got the answer to be 1.6 x 10^22 but the answer given in the textbook was 2.2 x 10^22. The method used in the solution book was different. They divided 1 cm³ by the volume of a unit cell (the side length was given).

Now both the answers are correct but in different contexts. Calculating by volume, I am finding out how many ccp unit cells are required to fill 1 cm³. But it's the same for any substance. But what I did is find out how many ccp unit cells are required to give the mass of 1 cm³ of aluminum. Now it's clear that the maximum possible number of ccp unit cells (2.2 x 10^22) are not being used. Why is that? It had been calculated earlier that ccp has a packing efficiency of 74% and 1.6 is actually 7.4 % but I'm not able to explain this.

Comment: What was the lattice parameter that was given? Did you check if that was correct?

Comment: Actually the atomic radius was given from which they had asked to calculate edge length. The atomic radium was given to be 125 pm from which I calculated the edge length to be 353 pm and it's the same in the solution book as well.

Comment: Better check that against tabulated values :)

Comment: Indeed! The atomic radius of aluminum is given as 143 pm and with that value the number of unit cells in 1 cm^3 is the same value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which book? Which page? The textbook erratum tag needs exact reference.

Comment: NCERT Chemistry for PU II part - 1. Chapter 1. Solids page number 32, exercise number 1.24.